# KnexJS Postgres: Adds extra double quotation marks to raw like query

Tags: postgresql, knex.js

Consider below code:

```
const items = await Item.query().where(
      "type",
      "like",
      raw("'??'", [`%${term}%`])
);
```

I'm not getting any errors with the code above, but the database returns an empty result set. The created SQL query is below:

```
select "items".* from "items" where type LIKE '%"mobiles"%'
```

Please look at the like mobiles in the above SQL `'%"mobiles"%'` `""` are treated as part of the value and returns an empty result set.

How can avoid `""` in the query above?

Edit: Please note that I'm using ObjectionJS as well which uses Knex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`??` are supposed to be used for a column name.

I've 2 suggestions for you,

1. use the query without `raw` at all,

```js
const items = await Item.query().where('type', 'like', `%${term}%`);
```

2. use single `?`,

```js
const items = await Item.query().where('type', 'like', raw("'?'", [`%${term}%`]));
```